# Image won't fill complete width of container

Tags: html, css

My image slider isn't quite the way I want it.

The image won't fill the full width of the container unless my browser window is small. When my window is larger the right side of the image has a white space instead of the image filling the whole width.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="6500" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
 <div class="fill">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="active item carousel-fade">

               <img src="EvanHeathYellowGreen.jpg" alt="Evan&MEKiss" > 

            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <img src="EvanCrossStreet.jpg" alt="Evan&MEKiss" > 

            </div>

            <div class="item carousel-fade">

                <img src="EvanMeLook.jpg" alt="Evan&MEKiss" > 


            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.fill {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image:"path/to/image.jpg";
}



.carousel-inner{

 margin-left: auto;

}

.carousel{
    margin-top: 20px;
     border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; 


}
```

Comment: Are you giving "img{ width: 100%;}" Cause if the image is smaller than your container, well, it will cover only his size area.

https://jsfiddle.net/svztmyve/ -- Leave you this example.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the image you are trying to fill?

If they are the ones with `alt="Evan&MEKiss"` then you can try Alberto Rubio's answer:

```
.item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you are trying to fill the background-image, you can try tweaking background-image to use url:

```
background-image:url("path/to/image.jpg");
```

Here's a codepen example with placeholder images: http://codepen.io/fawyna/pen/VaOmqX